# batch file to copy the Most Recent File created

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to scripting and I've this script over the internet, can anyone please explain exactly how the following code works, line by line?

```
@echo off

set "source=C:\temp"
set "dest=c:\paste"

pushd "%source%" ||(
   echo.Source does not exist&pause&goto EOF)

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (
   'dir /A-D /OD /B') Do set "file=%%f"

popd

xcopy /d /i "%source%\%file%" "%dest%\"
```

Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, its not to complicated:

**`@echo off`**: Prevents the user from seeing what commands are bein inputed from the batch files (only output can be seen)

**`set "var=value"`**: Creates a varaible called `var` with the value of `value`

**`pushd "%source%" ||(echo.Source does not exist&pause&goto EOF)`**:

Changes the current directory to that of the value of varaible `source` and if there is any output (i.e If there is an error) it will pause and exit with the given erroro message

**`for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /A-D /OD /B') Do set "file=%%f"`**:

Will go through every folder in the current directory, and set the value of varaible `file` to its name. It will do this in alphabetical order, so the directory last in this order will be the value of `file`

**`popd`**: Sets the current directory to what it was before the last `pushd` command

**`xcopy /d /i "%source%\%file%" "%dest%\"`**: Copies whatever is the value of variable `file` in the direcotory which has been set to the value of `source`, and copies it to the the path of the variable `dest`

And thats it. If you want a better understanding of how to use these commands look for a tutorial.

Comment: @AlvinMovida Please make my answer correct if you found it useful

Comment: @Monacraft there's some errors in your text. It will not go trough every folder in the directory it will go trough every thing that is **NOT** a folder. Also it will do it in the date order (not alphabetical)

Comment: @ the OP: One point to note is that the `/d` switch in xcopy will only copy the file if the `source time is newer than the destination time`.  For a more robust batch file, if you always want this file copied, then remove the `/d` switch and FWIW the `/i` switch is not needed either.  See `XCOPY /?` at a cmd prompt for the help on these switches.

Comment: Thanks, never used `xcopy` actually, since my work revolves around basic batch jobs and ftp server set-up I just use `copy`